# Executing a simple stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is a simple stored procedure written in SQL Server Management Studio.

It compiles great but I have problems invoking it :(

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DetermineVoltage]
   @itemDescription varchar(225) ,
   @voltageRating varchar(225) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
       @voltageRating = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@itemDescription),
       charindex(' V', REVERSE(@itemDescription)) + 2,
    CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@itemDescription), charindex(' V', REVERSE(@itemDescription)) + 1) - charindex(' V', REVERSE(@itemDescription)) - 2))
   RETURN
END
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, when I execute this stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE  @voltageRating VARCHAR(225) 
exec dbo.DetermineVoltage['test 20V', @voltageRating]
```

I get an error

> Procedure or function 'DetermineVoltage' expects parameter '@voltageRating', which was not supplied.

There are many SO answers which discusses the same error message but when executed from a C# program.

But, in my case, how to execute a stored procedure within SQL Server Management Studio ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```sql
declare @voltageRating varchar(225);
exec dbo.DetermineVoltage 'test 20V', @voltageRating output;
```

As a side note, you might want to convert this procedure to a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

Comment: Cool. Works great. Thanks. Can you kindly tell me from where do you refer?  I googled a lot but could not find.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed `where do you refer` -- [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Comment: Thanks again. Time to sharpen my googling skills ;)